# How can I await provisioning of an LWC wire service?

Tags: lightning-web-components, promises

Seems like there has got to be a simple way to do this, I'm just not sure what it is.

What type of await statement do I need to ensure that a particular wire has provisioned its data before proceeding with my logic?

```
myVar;

async myFunc() {
    // need to wait for myList to be populated, i.e. for getMyList to complete

    this.myVar = this.myList[0];
}

myList;

@wire (apex_myMethod)
getMyList (result) {
    if (result.data) {
        this.myList = result.data;
    }
}
```